# How do I pass input in a div section in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have followed the answer with code in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34492527/7844583). It works perfectly but I can't pass the input to the controller. When I use

```
<div id="textarea" class="form-group">
<input type="text" name="skills[]" />
</div>
```

and display the data I get an empty array. When I use

```
<div id="textarea" class="form-group">
<input type="text" name="skills" />
</div>
```

I get null.
How can I pass the data to the controller?

This is the form structure

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('profile.store')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="profile-card" id="categories">
      <div class="form-group">
        <h5>Skill Set</h5>
        <div id="cat">
            <div class="form-row">
                <label>Skills<b><i>(Press comma(,) to confirm a skill)</i></b></label>
                <div id="textarea" class="form-group"><input type="text" name="skills" /></div>
            </div>
        </div>          
      </div>
      <button class="btn" >Next</button>
    </div><br>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color: #008081;">Submit</button>
</form>
```

This is the controller

```
public function store(Request $request){
    dd($request->all());
}
```

Comment: Post your controller code please, and the <form> tag.

Comment: check the action route if it is register `php artisan route:list`. If you can see `profile.store`

Comment: I can see it. It actually works because it saves all other data in the database. The only issue is for this input within the div with a #textarea id

Comment: try this $request->get('skills'); for just name="skills"